# How did Bram Stoker portray Count Dracula's "aroma"?

Tags: character-development, dracula, bram-stoker

How did Bram Stoker portray Count Dracula's scent? Did the Vampire smell in the same way the *bathe once a year if YOU'RE lucky* humans of the era around him smelled, or did he have a faint tell tale stench of the un-dead about him that he had to hide with perfume? Or did he have some other scent all together?

Comment: Here, have an UV to compensate.

Comment: What did you find when you read the book?

Comment: @GEdgar I found it to be a good read with material suitable for the site. How did you find the book, good, bad, indifferent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Bram Stoker's [*Dracula,*](http://literature.org/authors/stoker-bram/dracula/chapter-19.html) chapter 19:

> With a little trouble we found the key on the bunch and opened the
>   door. We were prepared for some unpleasantness, for as we were opening
>   the door a faint, malodorous air seemed to exhale through the gaps,
>   but none of us ever expected such an odour as we encountered. None of
>   the others had met the Count at all at close quarters, and when I had
>   seen him he was either in the fasting stage of his existence in his
>   rooms or, when he was bloated with fresh blood, in a ruined building
>   open to the air, but here the place was small and close, and the long
>   disuse had made the air stagnant and foul. There was an earthy smell,
>   as of some dry miasma, which came through the fouler air. But as to
>   the odour itself, how shall I describe it? It was not alone that it
>   was composed of all the ills of mortality and with the pungent, acrid
>   smell of blood, but it seemed as though corruption had become itself
>   corrupt. Faugh! It sickens me to think of it. Every breath exhaled by
>   that monster seemed to have clung to the place and intensified its
>   loathsomeness.